# What is general name of described math function

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci, math-functions

I need to know the name of this function, please help.
The idea of this function is that you have some number and you need to finding two biggest numbers from fibonacci sequence which you need to add to get this number. And method returns to you array of this fibonacci digits but the numbers in this array represented by 0 and 1 where two numbers 1 and all others 0. And the position of 1 in array is the same where the biggest numbers as in fibonacci seq.

For example i have fibonacci sequence {1,1,2,3,5,8,13}
Number = 11 so the two numbers from sequence will be 8 and 3

The output will be {0,0,0,1,0,1,0}

Its pretty famous as i remember and I'm not completeley sure but using of fibonacci is one of the solutions of it. Please help to get the name of it so i could find out more about it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not function, but [numeral system: Fibonacci coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_coding) - representation of integer as sum of Fib. numbers

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem that i was looking for